# Why multiple-cursor ask me on every line? How avoid this?

Tags: text-editing, multiple-cursors

emacs 26.1, multiple-cursor https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

Here my custom Elisp function that add some number(by default 1) to number.

```
(defun increment-number-at-point(number)
  (interactive (list (read-number "Input increment number: " 1)))
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (+ number (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c +") 'increment-number-at-point)
```

Nice it's work fine. But suppose I has this json and want to add to every **id** the number 400.
Example json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "finished": 2,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 3,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "finished": 4,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "finished": 5,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

The result must be:

```
[
  {
    "id": 400,
    "finished": 2,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 401,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 402,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 403,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

here my steps (use my custom function and multiple-cursor)

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. Use `C-c +` (increment-number-at-point)
5. [image]
6. Input **400** `RET`
7. It's **AGAIN** ask me about  number
   [image]
8. So it ask my about number **ON EVERY LINE**. It's not good.

Is it possible to set **ONLY ONCE** number (400) and replace on every line automatic?

Comment: Would it help if you customize the variables `mc/cmds-to-run-once` and/or `mc/always-run-for-all`?  I.e., If you have inadvertently added your custom function to the one once list, then manually delete that entry; if you don't want to be prompted at every cursor, then add your custom function to the run for all list.  See the section of the README.MD entitled "*Unknown commands*":  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el  Have a look inside the file `.mc-lists.el` ....

Comment: I added "increment-number-at-point" to file .mc-lists.el. But it not help. Again every time ask me about number for every line.

Comment: You need to read the number outside the function. Else as it gets called on each cursor you also have to input a number on each.

Comment: Do you mean to remove  "read-number" from my function ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the last question:

```
(defun add-to-number-atpt ()
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((regexp "\"id\": \\([0-9]+\\),"))
    (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "\"id\": "(number-to-string (+ 400 (string-to-number (match-string-no-properties 1))))",")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function gets called for each cursor (if it is added to `mc/always-run-for-all`) and therefore the number is also read for each cursor.

To get around this you could write a wrapper that reads the number once and then runs your command for all cursors.

```lisp
(defun my-mc/increment-number-at-cursors (number)
  "Increment numbers for all cursors by NUMBER."
  (interactive (list (read-number "Input increment number: " 1)))
  (mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors
   (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (increment-number-at-point number))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split your function into two.

- One, which is doing the work on one single cursor (`internal`).
- A second one, which is called once by the user (`cmd`). This function ensures, that the work is done by for every single cursor.

source code:

```
(defun foo--internal ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (+ number (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))

(defun foo-cmd (number)
  (interactive (list (read-number "Input increment number: " 1)))
  (if (fboundp 'mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors)
      (mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors #'foo--internal)
    (foo--internal)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c +") 'foo-cmd)
```